# double comparison to zero special case?

Tags: java, double

I'm initializing a double array:

```
double [] foo = new double[n];
```

My understanding is that the java language specification causes all the values in the array to be initialized to zero.

As I go through my algorithm, some of the entries in the array get set to a positive value.

So to check whether a particular element has a non-zero value set, is it safe to just use

```
if (foo[i] > 0.0)
```

or should I be using an epsilon there.  Or similarly if I want to know if a value has not been set, could I use `==` given that the zeros will not have been computed values, but the original initialized zeros?  Normally of course I would never use `==` to compare floating point numbers, but I wonder if this is a special case?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why would you want to use an epsilon? Are you suggesting checking if a cell is set with `if (foo[i] > ep)' where ep is greater than 0?

Comment: If you're trying to see which values are being set, it might be better to use a `Double[]`. Then you can use `null` to indicate a value has not be set.

Comment: Try java.lang.Double.compare()

Comment: `if (foo[i] != 0.0)` is perfectly fine, given your criteria.

Comment: (When a double array is initialized, the elements are set to *exactly* 0.0, and an `==` compare to that value will always be true.)

Comment: I think that with primitive type you are free to use standart operators like >= or ==, != and so on (it is up to your situation). I do not get the problem what you are solving...I think that you shouldn't go deep into such a simple thing and do not imagine problem which does not exist. ;)

Comment: For those who didn't understand what I was trying to do, I was just trying to make sure that using `== 0.0` or `!= 0.0` (or `> 0.0` would work for doubles in my case.  I know that usually with floating point numbers, you can't rely on exact equality due to rounding errors, and wanted to make sure that that would not be an issue in this case, where the zeros are not the result of a floating point computation but were initialized as exactly zero.

Comment: There's no arithmetic there and therefore there's no round-off error. Using `==` is perfect here. Except in case your own numbers may be zero and you want to tell them apart from "uninitialized".

Comment: Java floating point conversion causes rounding error if, and only if, the value being converted is not exactly representable in the floating point type. Zero is exactly representable in double, so no rounding error.

Comment: Thanks all.  That's what I thought, but I wanted to be 100% sure.

Comment: Doesn't zero actually have two exact representations in floating point, though (positive and negative)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double [] foo = new double[10];
    foo[5] = 10;                            // Sets the sixth element to 10
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        double val = foo[i];
        if (val != 0) {
            System.out.printf("foo[%d] = %f\n", i, val);
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs

```
 foo[5] = 10.000000
```

Comment: Of course, that doesn't prove anything.  But it's reasonably strong circumstantial evidence.

Comment: Well I think that we can rely, that right after the array is initialized all the values are `== 0.0` so it should be enough to test `!= 0.0`

Comment: @HotLicks New York's such a wonderful city. Although I was at the library today. The guys are very rude. I said, "I'd like a card." He says, "You have to prove you're a citizen of New York." So I stabbed him. - Emo Phillips

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem with using

```
if (foo[i] > 0.0)
```

Comment: But it's not checking to see if the element is non-zero.  And it is OK to use `==` to compare a `double` to zero, if the intent is to check for exactly zero.

Comment: Yes, it is OK to use ==.  But what you probably want to do is (if foo[i] != 0.0)

Comment: if I know my values are either going to be zero or a positive number, which is more computationally efficient: `if (x > 0.0)` or `if (x != 0.0)`?  Thanks!

Comment: It should be equivalent.  I might use ">" to slightly improve readability.