# If double a=0.0, can I compare a*b==0 directly?

Tags: java, double

I know double should not be compared by == operator directly, but how about if I define an initial value as 0.0?eg:

```
double a=0.0;
double b=
.
.
.
```

If a is not modified, does a*b==0 always true?

Comment: Have you tried writing a test (jUnit) and verifying yourself?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005444/double-comparison-to-zero-special-case?rq=1  FWIW, multiplication with 0 will make the result *exactly* 0 (no rounding errors or imprecisions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know double should not be compared by == operator direct

That is only true if you don't know how much representation or rounding error you have. A classic example of what not to do is

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 // false :(
```

However, if you use rounding like

```
if (round4(0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3) // true
```

from [Chronicle Core's Maths](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Core/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/core/Maths.java#L91)

```
public static double round4(double d) {
    final double factor = 1e4;
    return d > WHOLE_NUMBER / factor || d < -WHOLE_NUMBER / factor ? d :
            (long) (d < 0 ? d * factor - 0.5 : d * factor + 0.5) / factor;
}
```

> If a is not modified, does a*b==0 always true?

It is for finite numbers. For infinity and `NaN` you will get `NaN` and this is not equal to anything.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication with `0.0` will result in `0.0` (exactly, no rounding errors or other imprecisions -- unless stuff like infinity or NaN are involved).

But if you end up with `0.0` or something close to `0.0` after arbitrary operations, you cannot be sure if it is really (mathematically) 0, and should use an epsilon.